crypto-js encryption method doubling the size
I'm working on a project where I'm using Crypto.JS to encrypt image data. However, I'm encountering a significant size increase after encryption, exceeding the expected 33% overhead. What factors might contribute to this unexpected size increase, and how can I mitigate it while maintaining a secure encryption solution?
  const handleEncrypt = () => {
    if (imageFile) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
      reader.onload = () => {
        const imageData = reader.result.split(',')[1]; 
        const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(imageData, 'secret-key').toString();
        setEncryptedData(encrypted);
      };
    }
  };

  const handleDownload = () => {
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    const file = new Blob([encryptedData], { type: 'text/plain' });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = 'encrypted_image.txt';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
  };


I expecting changes in the code might helps to reduce the size or any alternate methods to overcome the issue

And what's your goal? I mean, client-side encryption with a well-known secret key (it's public as soon as someone loads your app) adds very little to security, if anything. Why do you need such a step?

CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(imageData, 'secret-key').toString() applies a key derivation function (if the key material is passed as string) and returns the Base64 encoding of the ASCII encoding of Salted__ plus 8 bytes salt plus ciphertext, which is naturally longer than the Base64 encoding of the ciphertext alone. However, this generally does not mean doubling. Can you quantify unexpected size increase (size of imageData, size of encrypted)?
